# Why is linux-image-extra missing from 3.8.9 onwards?

Tags: kernel, 13.04, ppa

I've been using kernels from Ubuntu kernel team PPA for some time now. I have setup a script that wget's all the four files required for my setup: all the amd64+all headers, total of 4 files. [Kernel 3.8.8 for example](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8.8-raring/).

In [3.8.9](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8.9-raring/) and [3.9](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/), there is no longer linux-image-extra package.

1. Why was it dropped?
2. Is the functionality it provided now included in the main package?
3. Who is affected?

Comment: I look forward to seeing the answer from someone who knows the answer, but I will say that I installed it and it is working fine for me.  I looked at the file sizes and saw that the total of the three files comes to about what the previous four used to be, so it seemed likely to me that the functionaliy is now contained in those three files.

Comment: image-extra is also present in 3.9rc1-rc6, just saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image-extra` was merged with `linux-image`

source:

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139230
2. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2013-April/027820.html